# Why do I have this error ? (unable to decode message length:.....)

Tags: mongodb-atlas

I use node gtfs library, who use a mongo database.
I adjusted the lib to run with a mongo atlas database, it works fine and my datas are loaded in the database.
The library delete the content of the database each time we use it, and it works for a part of the datas but not for the largest datas.

error:

```
errmsg:
   'connection(xxxxxx-xxxxx-00-02-gefgq.mongodb.net:27017[-13721]) unable to decode message length: read tcp xx.xxx.xxx.xx:49556->xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017: i/o timeout',
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const routes = require("./routes/routes.js")(app);

const server = app.listen(3001, function () {
    console.log("Listening on port %s...", server.address().port);
});

const gtfs = require('gtfs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./gtfs-config.json');

mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl, {dbName: 'gtfs', useNewUrlParser: true});

gtfs.import(config)
.then(() => {
    console.log('Import Successful');
    return mongoose.connection.close();
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```